# how to properly specify an IP for a docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to explicitly specify an IP address for my docker container in the following way:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 172.17.0.2:10000:10000 -p 9000:9000 -p 9090:9090 -v /home/eugene/dev/shared:/opt/shared -d eugene/dev_img_1.3
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b2242e5da6e1b701ba4880f25fa8d465d5f008787b49898ad9e46eb26e417e48: port has already been allocated
```

I really do not care about port 10000. My goal is to have a specific container IP of my choosing, as well as to have ports 9000 and 9090 exposed to the host.

I have looked at some other questions, but did not see a clear syntax to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p` argument is used to forward ports from the container to the host, not for assigning IPs.

There is no easy way to assign a fixed IP to a Docker container and I would strongly advise you not to try. Instead re-architect your system so that it isn't dependent on a fixed IP. If this really isn't possible, I think you can choose an IP by using the LXC execution driver and various flags, but I would strongly recommend against this.

Comment: In my container I run /usr/sbin/sshd among other things, and I need to know from the host - what IP I can ssh to

Comment: Could you just run `docker inspect -f "{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" CONTAINER` to find the IP? Also, if possible, prefer `docker exec` to ssh.

Comment: I guess I would settle for mapping container's port 22 to some higher port on the host. would that be in a form of -p 22:22222 or the other way around?

Comment: Other way around: `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`. Note you can also use `-P` which will automatically assign a high numbered port for each exposed container port, which is handy if you have several containers with similar services.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in different ways.

You can edit your system-wide Docker server settings (by editing DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker) and add the option `--ip=IP_ADDRESS` in Ubuntu and then restart your server. If you are using only 1 docker container and want to have dockers IP same as your host, start the docker container using `--net=host` flag to set the container to have the host machine IP address.

Other way is to have these options configured at server startup(by editing DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker):
`--bip=CIDR` — to supply a specific IP address and netmask for the "docker0" bridge, using standard notation like 192.168.1.8/23. 
For example with `--fixed-cidr=192.168.1.0/25`, IPs for your containers will be chosen from the first half of 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. The "docker0" Ethernet bridge settings are used every time you create a new container. You are trying to bind a container's ports to a specific port using the `-p` flag , which will not help you in assigning a IP address to the container.

Another way to assign a IP address in any particular range(Example: 172.30.1.21/30). Stop the docker using `stop docker` , then use `ip link` and `ip addr` commands to set up the "bridge br0" and start docker using `docker -d -b br0`

Comment: --ip is not recognized by docker

Comment: Can you tell me how you are using it ?? Please look at how to use it properly. Here are some of the links from the official docker website https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/,  https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#binding-ports

Comment: here is how I'm using it:   sudo docker run -it -p 9000:9000 -p 9090:9090 --ip=172.17.0.2 -v /home/eugene/shared:/opt/shared -d eugenegoldberg/dev_img_1.2

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your requirements. I guess the 2nd part of the answer is most suitable for your requirements.

Comment: I ran:     sudo docker run -it -p 9000:9000 -p 9090:9090 --fixed-cidr=172.17.0.2/24 -v /home/eugene/dev/shared:/opt/shared -d eugenegoldberg/dev_img_1.2    - and got:    flag provided but not defined: --fixed-cidr

Comment: This is a wrong way of using it. They are not flags. You need to edit it in the specified location. Please go through the above links i mentioned. Try to understand how its used as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70406/discussion-between-programminggeek-and-eugene-goldberg).

Comment: `--ip` sets the IP address of the _host_ that is used for the bound port. My understanding is that the OP wants to set the IP address of the _container_. (@programmingGeek, I think you understand this, but I'm not sure it will be clear to others).

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a fixed ip using [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework), but it's not "the docker way".  I would agree with Adrian.  Re-design away from fixed IP's.

Comment: In my container I run /usr/sbin/sshd among other things, and I need to know from the host - what IP I can ssh to

Comment: Publish the port up to the host?